# Why is my django urlpattern not resolving?

Tags: python, django, django-views

So I'm creating a small ecommerce website for a friend and cannot work out why the url won't resolve itself.

For the sake of simplicity whilst making the website I'm using a product called "number 1". It has a slug field of "number-1" and on the product page clicking on the product takes a user to "/shop/number-1"

My url pattern for this is:

```
url(r'^<slug:url>', views.item, name='products')
```

with the view:

```
def item(request, url=""):
    products = product.objects.get(url=url)
    return render(request, 'shop\product.html', {'products', products})
```

As far as I can tell this should render my product.html template but instead it returns a 404 and I'm not sure why?

If it helps I have other views, such as product types set within the same views and they work fine so as far as I can tell its that the slug:url isn't being used in the views.item, or the view isn't getting the context properly.

Also I'm on django 1.11.7 for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url pattern you are trying to use (`slug:url`) is [only valid in Django 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#simplified-url-routing-syntax).

If you are on Django 1.11 then you need to use a regular expression - something like this:

```
url(r'^?P<url>[\w-]+', views.item, name='products')
```

Always make sure you're looking at the documentation for [your version of Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/) ;-).

Comment: It wouldn't be valid even in Django 2, because you need to use `path()` not `url()`.

Answer (score 0):

Please change url pattern to:

```
url(r'^?P<url>[\w-]+', views.item, name='products')
```